# row names supplied are of the wrong length in R

Tags: r

I am running a R program that computes similarity between product descriptions. The input to the program is a file with 1 column, containing the list of Product Descriptions, each on a separate row

I have another file that contains the list of product titles, each on a separate row.

Using dist function, I have computed the similarity between product descriptions and they are stored in dist.mat as a matrix.

Next, I want to join product title to this similarity that I have computed. So, I read the Product Titles in Names and then:

```
dist.mat <- data.frame(dist.mat, row.names=Names[,1])  
colnames(dist.mat) <- (row.names(dist.mat))
```

and then I get an error:
   Error in data.frame(dist.mat, row.names = Names[, 1]) : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length

Not really sure on how to fix it. I read this: [Invalid 'row.names' length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739666/invalid-row-names-length) but I can't fix the error using Sample$ or as.character

I am using: lsa_0.73, SnowballC_0.5.1, tm_0.5-10

Here is an actual example:
**Product Desc file:**

- This glass can be used to drink whiskey
- This is a stainless steel glass
- This is a red rose

**Product Title File:**

- Whiskeyglass
- glass
- rose

[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHKNV.png)

Would be great if someone can help

Comment: Could you please tell me about the `Whiskeyglass` string.  Is it counted as one or two words?

Comment: @akrun: Whiskeyglass is counted as 1 word

Comment: I am trying to understand how you got the values in the output file.  Can you please update with the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance matrix (class `dist`) for a vector is displayed as one row and one column smaller triangular matrix than the vector length.

```
library(stringdist)

desc <- c("This glass can be used to drink whiskey",
   "This is a stainless steel glass",
   "This is a red rose")

Names <- c("Whiskeyglass", "glass", "rose")

dist.mat1 <- stringdistmatrix(desc)
dist.mat1
#    1  2
# 2 27   
# 3 24 18
```

However, a `dist` object does not have dimensions and therefore row and column names cannot be assigned to it.

```
dim(dist.mat1)
# NULL
```

Trying to name the rows and columns of a `dist`object results in an error.

```
row.names(dist.mat1) <- colnames(dist.mat1) <- Names
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
>     cannot coerce class ""dist"" to a data.frame

To obtain the result you expect, a `dist` object first needs to be converted to a `matrix`. This adds the zeros along a diagonal and thus also a row and a column.

```
if(class(dist.mat1) == "dist"){
    dist.mat2 <- as.matrix(dist.mat1)
    row.names(dist.mat2) <- colnames(dist.mat2) <- Names
} else {
    dist.mat2 <- dist.mat1
    row.names(dist.mat2) <- colnames(dist.mat2) <- Names
}

dist.mat2
#              Whiskeyglass glass rose
# Whiskeyglass            0    27   24
# glass                  27     0   18
# rose                   24    18    0
```

If your `dist.mat` looks like `dist.mat1` above, but its class is `matrix`, then you need to select which Names belong where.

```
row.names(dist.mat) <- Names[-1]             # removing the first name for rows
colnames(dist.mat) <- Names[-length(Names)]  # removing the last name for columns
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, the rownames is not of the same length as the number of columns because when we add a new column with `row.names=Names[,1]` obviously, there will be one more column.  So, I guess this can be fixed

```
 colnames(dist.mat)[-ncol(dist.mat)] <- row.names(dist.mat)
```

Instead of having the `row.names` column as the last one, it may be better to have it as first column

```
dist.mat1 <- data.frame(rn = row.names(Names[,1]), dist.mat) 
colnames(dist.mat1)[-1] <- row.names(dist.mat)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, I have a different error:  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 30.. May be it's my input file?

Comment: @user5712288  It implies that the length of `Names[,1]` is not matching with the new dataset.  Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to comment.

Comment: I updated with a small example, you are probably looking for output sample - but it is hard for me to show that here in stackoverflow as I don't know how to make a table

Comment: @user5712288  Without an output, how do we know what you wanted

Comment: Done, added a screenshot